# Preencher data e hora na View mvc 5 razor

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Eu tenho um formulário de cadastro onde tenho um campo data de registro que atualmente eu preencho no meu método de salvar, só que meu servidor está hospedado em outro pais onde o campo esta sendo preenchido da localização da hospedagem, bem diferente de onde o sistema vai ser executado e os horários não batem então gostaria da ajuda de como pegar a hora do navegador e passar no meu submit do meu  formulário, acredito que de para fazer via javascript ou com o próprio razor.

Comment: Especifique no `web.config` as configurações de regionalidade da aplicação. Ex: `<system.web><globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/></system.web>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JavaScript**

Com JavaScript basta usar o `new Date()`.

Fiz o exemplo abaixo pegando a data, formatando com o [`toLocaleString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn412711(v=vs.94).aspx) e jogando num campo input text.

```js
var dataAtual = new Date();

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#campoData").val(dataAtual.toLocaleString())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Data de hoje: <input id="campoData" type="text">
```

---

**C#**

Com o C# você pode usar o [Timezone](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timezone?view=netframework-4.7.2). Segue Exemplo:

```
DateTime dataRussia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, 
"Russian Standard Time");
```

Caso queira ver a lista de TimeZoneIds, pode fazer isso:

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    Console.WriteLine(timeZone .Id);
}
```

**Abaixo a lista de Timezone:**

> Dateline Standard Time
>
> UTC-11
>
> Samoa Standard Time
>
> Hawaiian Standard Time
>
> Alaskan Standard Time
>
> Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Pacific Standard Time
>
> US Mountain Standard Time
>
> Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Mountain Standard Time
>
> Central America Standard Time
>
> Central Standard Time
>
> Central Standard Time (Mexico)
>
> Canada Central Standard Time
>
> SA Pacific Standard Time
>
> Eastern Standard Time
>
> US Eastern Standard Time
>
> Venezuela Standard Time
>
> Paraguay Standard Time
>
> Atlantic Standard Time
>
> Central Brazilian Standard Time
>
> SA Western Standard Time
>
> Pacific SA Standard Time
>
> Newfoundland Standard Time
>
> E. South America Standard Time
>
> Argentina Standard Time
>
> SA Eastern Standard Time
>
> Greenland Standard Time
>
> Montevideo Standard Time
>
> UTC-02
>
> Mid-Atlantic Standard Time
>
> Azores Standard Time
>
> Cape Verde Standard Time
>
> Morocco Standard Time
>
> UTC
>
> GMT Standard Time
>
> Greenwich Standard Time
>
> W. Europe Standard Time
>
> Central Europe Standard Time
>
> Romance Standard Time
>
> Central European Standard Time
>
> W. Central Africa Standard Time
>
> Namibia Standard Time
>
> Jordan Standard Time
>
> GTB Standard Time
>
> Middle East Standard Time
>
> Egypt Standard Time
>
> Syria Standard Time
>
> South Africa Standard Time
>
> FLE Standard Time
>
> Israel Standard Time
>
> E. Europe Standard Time
>
> Arabic Standard Time
>
> Arab Standard Time
>
> Russian Standard Time
>
> E. Africa Standard Time
>
> Iran Standard Time
>
> Arabian Standard Time
>
> Azerbaijan Standard Time
>
> Mauritius Standard Time
>
> Georgian Standard Time
>
> Caucasus Standard Time
>
> Afghanistan Standard Time
>
> Ekaterinburg Standard Time
>
> Pakistan Standard Time
>
> West Asia Standard Time
>
> India Standard Time
>
> Sri Lanka Standard Time
>
> Nepal Standard Time
>
> Central Asia Standard Time
>
> Bangladesh Standard Time
>
> N. Central Asia Standard Time
>
> Myanmar Standard Time
>
> SE Asia Standard Time
>
> North Asia Standard Time
>
> China Standard Time
>
> North Asia East Standard Time
>
> Singapore Standard Time
>
> W. Australia Standard Time
>
> Taipei Standard Time
>
> Ulaanbaatar Standard Time
>
> Tokyo Standard Time
>
> Korea Standard Time
>
> Yakutsk Standard Time
>
> Cen. Australia Standard Time
>
> AUS Central Standard Time
>
> E. Australia Standard Time
>
> AUS Eastern Standard Time
>
> West Pacific Standard Time
>
> Tasmania Standard Time
>
> Vladivostok Standard Time
>
> Central Pacific Standard Time
>
> New Zealand Standard Time
>
> UTC+12
>
> Fiji Standard Time
>
> Kamchatka Standard Time
>
> Tonga Standard Time

Referências:

- [TimeZoneInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timezone?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Método ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908482/5522115)

Comment: Sucesso! muito obrigado. @George Wurthmann